# hibernate ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, swap, hibernate

I have both windows and Ubuntu installed on my PC. It has 16 GB of RAM, initially it didn't have any Linux swap partition so I created one of size 10GB [image: screen shot of my disk]

Even though i have sufficient swap size, i cannot hibernate my PC using

> sudo pm-hibernate

it just shuts the screen off for few seconds but doesn't turnoff the system.

Comment: How is 10GB sufficient for 16GB? 10<16! Also, it doesn't seem to make sense to save so much data, and then re-read it.

Comment: to hibernate your machine, Ubuntu must write out the contents of your ram (16gb) into the unused swap space available (11gb). Swap space must be greater than RAM (plus any swap space in use at time of hibernate).

Comment: i increased the swap size to 20GB but still the problem exists